# Calculate $f'(i)$ where $f(z)=z^{1+i}$

Tags: complex-analysis

The question is: Let $f(z)$ denote the principal branch of $z^{1+i}$ and calculate $f'(i)$.
My attempt: put $w=1+i$
$$z^w=e^{wLogz} e^{2\pi kiw} $$
$$(z^w)'=e^{wLogz}(Logz)' e^{2\pi kiw} $$
$$(z^w)'=\dfrac{1}{z}e^{wLogz} e^{2\pi kiw} $$
$$(z^w)'=\dfrac{1}{z}e^{wlog|z|+iArgz}e^{2\pi kiw}$$
so $$f'(z)=\dfrac{1}{z}e^{wlog|z|+iArgz}e^{2\pi kiw} $$
and plug in i into $f'(z)$ which gave me
$$f'(i)=-i\exp({1+i+i(\dfrac{\pi}{2}+2\pi k(1+i)})) $$
Is this correct or did I mess up from the beginning?

Comment: Think I made one mistake when putting in i into f'(z), $wlog|i|$ should vanish since $log|i|=0$. However, I'm still not sure if this attempt is correct..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's really quite simple.

Differentiate the usual way (power rule):

$f(z) = z^{1+i}$

$f'(z)=(1+i)z^i$

$f'(i) = (1+i)i^i$

and you now need to find the general form of $i^i$. You do that by writing the $i$ in the base as $i = e^{i(\frac{\pi}{2}+2k\pi)}, k \in \mathbb{Z}$ and leave the exponent as it is.

You then get:

$f'(i) = (1+i)i^i = (1+i)e^{i\cdot (i(\frac{\pi}{2}+2k\pi))} = (1+i)e^{-\frac{\pi}2-2k\pi} \\ =e^{-\frac{\pi}2(1+4k)}(1+i) , k \in \mathbb{Z}$

The principal value is generally found by setting $k=0$ and that is $\mathbb {pv} \ f'(i) = e^{-\frac{\pi} 2}(1+i)$.

Comment: It was really simple, but then I have another question when do you use $z^{\alpha}=e^{(\alpha Logz)}e^{(2\pi ikw)}$? Is it only used for defining complex powers?